# What is the benefit of readonly in PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, oop, immutability, php-8.1

In PHP 8.1, the readonly keyword is now available. I am curious about its purpose. Is it intended to assist the editor in recognizing that a property is solely readonly, to aid the client in understanding this characteristic, or does it serve another purpose?

Comment: The main benefit is that it helps create immutable data structures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). It was possible to do that in PHP prior version 8.1 by creating a getter for a property and no setter, but the readonly keyword achieves the same thing in a much more readable and shorter form.

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/readonly_properties_v2 contains the argumentation taken to get this feature into PHP, maybe that helps already?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`readonly` properties allow you to create immutable objects, or at the very least immutable properties.

That way you can be sure that a value won't be changed by accident after being initialized, throughout the object's life.

It's a very similar concept to constants (set via `const` or `define`), albeit with two important differences:

- constants need to be defined on "compilation" time, whereas `readonly` properties will be set during runtime, usually during on object instantiation (so multiple instances will be able to hold different values*)
- constants live in the global scope; and in case of class constants, their value is tied to the class and not to the instance.

You **could** achieve the same with a private property only accessible via a getter. E.g., in "the olden days":

```
class Foo {

    private DateTimeImmutable $createAt;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->createdAt = new DateTimeImmutable();
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
echo $f->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The only problem with this is that it requires a lot of boilerplate code.

With PHP 8.1, almost the same could be achieved by doing:

```
class Foo
{

    public function __construct(
        public readonly DateTimeImmutable $createdAt = new DateTimeImmutable()
    )
    { }

}

$f = new Foo();
echo $f->createdAt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

And since PHP 8.2 add `readonly` classes, it gets even better, since one can do:

```
readonly class Foo
{

    public function __construct(
        public string $name,
        public DateTimeImmutable $createdAt = new DateTimeImmutable()
    )
    { }

}
```

And now both `Foo::name` and `Foo::createdAt` are `readonly`, and can only be set during object instantiation.